# How to set the default browser from within a shell script

Tags: applications, pantheon-terminal, shell

I am trying to write a shell script that automates the setup of my Elementary distro so I can quickly reinstall everything on a new machine. As such I am looking to see how I can set the default browser from within a shell script, preferable without user input. Thanks!
Luke

Answer (score 2):

I found this could be done with
xdg-settings set default-web-browser brave-browser.desktop

where brave-browser.desktop is the desktop file of the desired browser